# How disqus comments (inside cross domain iframe) are indexed by google?

Tags: seo, googlebot, comments, disqus

According to what I have read is that google doesn't index content from any cross domain iframe since it's the content of another website. So how does Disqus do it?

Answer (score 7):

This is because what you had read is not fully true, as Google [says](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34445?hl=en):

> Google tries to associate framed content with the page containing the
>   frames, but we don't guarantee that we will.

Or it was before 2011, when Matt Cutts from Google [said](https://twitter.com/mattcutts/status/131425949597179904):

> Googlebot keeps getting smarter. Now has the ability to execute
>   AJAX/JS to index some dynamic comments

Disqus comments **are being indexed by Google**, (Facebook comments too), I have tested myself and I can find Disqus comments in SERP.

From a previous Disqus statement they [said](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520191004/https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/526768-introducing-the-new-disqus-and-f-a-q-) regarding *iframes*:

> we decided to completely re-implement our commenting embed inside of
>   an iframe. This iframe is hosted on disqus.com and, as such, the
>   browser won't let your website apply styles to it using CSS
>   statements. We did this for a few very important reasons:
>
> The iframe is part of our solution to provide full indexing of Disqus comments by Google and other search engines, without having to
>   duplicate content on your website (e.g., through a WordPress plugin).

And about Google [indexing](https://web.archive.org/web/20130708143840/http://disqus.com/for-websites/control-and-seo) comments:

> Disqus is fully indexable for search engines out- of-the-box. We have
>   been approved by the Google Search Quality team to be organically
>   crawled unlike any other comment platform.

So Google bot has become *"intelligent"* enough to realize that the iframe content are comments related to each webpage and **can be indexed**, they are not just displaying content from other webpage, but at the end, Google always has [the last word](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/762307-why-isn-t-google-indexing-my-comments-):

> While Disqus implements the necessary functionality for Google to
>   crawl comments, indexing comments is at Google's discretion.

Comment: thank you for your efforts but I still don't know what can I do to index comments inside an iframe on my website like disqus.